# What changes are in the Lumia Black update, and when will it be released?

Tags: lumia, lumia-black-update

After **Lumia Amber**, Nokia is going to release **Lumia Black** update. What are the major features of this update? When it will available to developers and end users?

Comment: As of first googling I got, **Glance Screen** : *Colors & notifications*, **Camera** : *RAW Camera support & New camera algorithms*, **Bluetooth 4.0 LE**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What’s in it?**

The official Nokia Conversations blog today has the full scoop on the new update and even more pretty screenshots. But here’s a brief rundown on some of the goodies Lumia owners can expect:

**App Folder** A new Start screen feature for grouping similar apps and settings, making it easier to personalize and organize your phone.

**Nokia Glance screen 2.0** Saves you time and taps by keeping important notifications—phone, text, email, calendar, and notifications from apps like Twitter and Facebook—visible at a glance.

**Bluetooth LE** Is coming to the entire Windows Phone 8 Lumia range—big news for fans of the Adidas MiCoach Smart Run watch and other Bluetooth LE compatible gadgets.

**Nokia Refocus** This magical imaging app lets you capture first and re-focus later, creating sharable interactive photos that have to be seen to be believed. (Requires 1GB RAM or more.)

**Nokia Beamer** Beam documents, presentations, and whatever else you like to any HTML5-enabled screen by scanning a QR code. (Requires 1GB RAM or more.)

**Nokia Storyteller** Already available on the Lumia 1520 and 2520, the Storyteller app arranges your photos by date and place, and then locates them on an interactive map, to create stories from your snapshots.

**Nokia Camera** Combines two of Nokia’s most lauded photography apps—Pro Camera and Smart Camera—into one powerful and easy-to-use package. Already available on Lumia PureView smartphones, the Black update brings it to the rest of Nokia’s Windows Phone 8 lineup.

As you can see, there are lots of goodies in this new update for hardcore shutterbugs. But there’s even more than what I mentioned above. Lumia Black also brings raw DNG support to Lumia 1020 owners. DNG is a lossless imaging format that pros swear by and allows you to be more creative with your images. The update also further refines overall image quality, especially on the Lumia 1020.

*Source* [http://blogs.windows.com/](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2014/01/09/nokia-kicks-off-lumia-black-software-update-with-new-features-apps.aspx)

Comment: This answer is copy&pasted from the source. I'm not sure what StackExchange's policy is for non-CC sources.

Answer (score 17):

The Lumia Black update comes with the [GDR3 update](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2013/10/14/announcing-our-third-windows-phone-8-update-plus-a-new-developer-preview-program.aspx) and adds extra features to their Windows Phone 8 Lumia range. The official rollout has begun on [January 9th, 2014](http://conversations.nokia.com/2014/01/09/lumia-black-update/).

**GDR3 features**

- **Accessibility**. Several improvements for customers who are visually impaired.
- **Storage**. Now you can easily free up storage space on your phone and manage temporary files. New categories show what’s taking up space.
- **Driving Mode**. Feeling distracted behind the wheel? Driving Mode allows you to minimize incoming calls and text messages to help you focus on the road.
- **Screen**. Reading emails in bed? You can lock your screen orientation so it doesn’t shift when you move your phone around.
- **Wi-Fi**. Start preserving cellular data on your phone right out of the box—you can now connect to Wi-Fi during set up.
- **Internet sharing**. Now you can use your phone’s cellular data connection from your Microsoft Windows 8.1 devices by pairing them over Bluetooth.
- **Bluetooth**. Several fixes were made to address known issues, and improvements were made to connection quality for Bluetooth accessories.
- **Ringtones**. Do more with ringtones now. Assign ringtones for text messages, so you’ll know who’s texting you without even looking. Use your custom ringtones for more things—text messages, instant messages, emails, voicemail, and reminders.
- **App switcher**. Don’t look back. Now you can use the App switcher to quickly close apps when you’re finished with them.
- **Other improvements**. Includes many other improvements to Windows Phone.

Source: [MobileSyrup](http://mobilesyrup.com/2013/11/29/telus-says-the-gdr3-update-will-come-to-the-nokia-lumia-520-620-and-1020-in-january/)

**Lumia Black features**

- **Glance Screen** – green, blue, and red colors
- **Glance Screen** – notifications
- RAW Camera support for Lumia 1020 and Lumia 1520
- Bluetooth 4.0 LE
- New camera algorithms
- App folders
- Improved Nokia beamer app

Source: [Windows Phone Central](http://www.wpcentral.com/nokia-prepping-lumia-black-software-update-asking-users-help-testing), [Nokia](http://conversations.nokia.com/2014/01/09/lumia-black-update/)

**Release date**

According to various reports, the Lumia Black update is due for release in "early 2014" with some sources saying "January 2014".

As with previous Windows Phone 8 updates, when the rollout starts, it can take upto 2 months for all phones and carriers to approve and release the update.

**For developers**

GDR3 contains no new APIs but developers can customise their apps slightly to support the new 1080p display used in the Lumia 1520.

Microsoft is expected to release updated emulator images for the Windows Phone 8 SDK in the coming weeks, so that developers can properly test their apps against GDR3 and the new 1080p screen resolution.

Comment: I got these little information from same site *Windows Phone Central*. I hope these are not full specifications list.

Comment: @NK Probably it is since plain GDR3 there isn't so much news. I already played with this in a HTC8X.

Comment: @NK Adding to Victor's comment, GDR3 is mostly bug fixes and support for new hardware. Nokia are adding a couple of new features in the Black update. Expect exciting new features in the WP 8.1 update due early next year.

Comment: Black is NOT a "combination of the GDR3 update and some extra features by Nokia for their Windows Phone 8 Lumia range."  Black and GDR3 are two separate updates, the former by Nokia and the latter by Microsoft.  In fact, many have already installed GDR3 using Microsoft's new Developer Preview Program.

Comment: @RichHopkins I've changed the wording. Although you are correct, most people will get both updates together as with Amber.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some of the [issues I had with the SD card performance and general phone slowness](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/windows-phone-8-slower-with-sdcard-in-than-without/2639#2639) were resolved for me.

The performance of the typing and scrolling generally feel faster for me too