# Nokia Lumia 920 can get updated to GDR3?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, gdr-3

Microsoft released `GDR3` this November but I can't get updating it yet.
I googled it to find out but there is no information.

Do Nokia and Microsoft even have a plan to update Lumia 920 to GDR3?

Comment: Although GDR3 was released as-is for some phones starting in Nov, Nokia release it as part of their Lumia Black update which started a few days ago - starting with the Lumia 1020. More handsets should start receiving the Black Update in Jan 2014.

Comment: @NeilTurner what does `Black update` mean?

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2788/what-changes-are-in-the-lumia-black-update-and-when-will-it-be-released) for more info

Answer (score 3):

It is up to your carrier to release the update. All WP8 phones are eligible to upgrade to the latest updates. If you do not wish to wait, Microsoft has released an [app](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=178ac8a1-6519-4a0b-960c-038393741e96) where "developers" can upgrade to Update 3 early. Note that you need to be ["qualified"](http://www.theverge.com/2013/10/14/4837204/windows-phone-8-update-3-developer-preview-download) as a developer (it doesn't take much).

Comment: Thank for the links! But I didn't upgrade via `Preview for developers` yet because it looks like `Preview GDR3`. Are they same code?

Comment: The preview is ahead of what HTC8x already received. Unfortunately until today the differences from the already RTM version and the newest version are only some bug fixes.